# Accounting for differences in average teacher salaries, adjusted for inflation and the cost of living in each state

Tags: econometrics

My aim is to determine whether teacher salaries in all 50 of the United States over between 2013 and 2023—adjusted for inflation and the cost of living—differ significantly. I would like to ask what the wisest approach might be to modify unadjusted teacher salary averages (there is one average for each state) to account for these effects.

Afterwards, I would like to graph these modified salaries for a few of these states and examine whether changes in revenue receipts within all schools in a particular state leads to a significant difference in average salaries.

I am open to your insight on how I might best tweak teachers’ salaries to account for these effects and things I ought to consider when graphing the relationship I’ve described. Please bear in mind that I am referring to information from the National Education Association, which sources from public schools.

Thank you!

Comment: [cross posting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/121894) is generally [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/989943).

Comment: I guess the only within-state variability you can measure is year by year. States with consistent means will make for comparisons that are statistically more significant. But is that what you or your audience cares about?  I doubt that statistical significance will serve you here.

Comment: "Hypothesis testing is admirably suited for the allaying of insecurities which might have been better left unallayed."
Jerome Cornfield

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I agree! My objective here to see why a particular state's average teacher salaries hasn't risen enough. In this context, enough means that as school districts in this state receive more money than other states' schools, this state's teachers should earn more. That said, up to this point, I've gathered average salaries for teachers in every state over the past decade, divide the salary by the real value of a US dollar in each state, and compare percentage changes. Before investigating further, I'd be grateful if you could critique my methodology.